# YII2 project not accessible in root directory

Tags: yii2

I have xampp installed and then I my project is accessible in the browser using `localhost/project`. I want it to be accessible just as `localhost`. I tried moving the content of `project` outside but `localhost` does not work.

Comment: dude you are going places how can you run the php project outside the localhost, what you are looking for is the virtual domain on local computer.

Comment: What i mean is outside the project folder so that it will be in the htdocs folder directly without any sub folder.

Comment: and if you would have searched for the term virtual host you would have unleashed a more advanced way of making your project work the way you want by keeping the directory and files still on the same place , for example how about you could run your yii project by typing `www.myproject.local` or `myproject.local` or `cantunderstand.com`

Comment: thank you for being so nice. :)